# Using enum in WCF service

Tags: wcf, web-services

I have a WCF web service written in c#
I have an enum

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "NameSpace")]
public enum State
{
        [EnumMember]
        NotAvailable = 1,
        [EnumMember]
        RunningTests = 3,
        [EnumMember]
        ReadyForTests = 4,
        [EnumMember]
        HungOrBroken = 5
}
```

Then I run following commands to generate .h, .cpp files I can use in my MFC application.

```
svcutil.exe /t:metadata <webservice dll>
WSUtil.exe /prefix:Ws *.wsdl *.xsd
```

Above commands generate files that have:

```
typedef enum WsState
{
    WsStateHungOrBroken = 0,
    WsStateNotAvailable = 1,
    WsStateReadyForTests = 2,
    WsStateRunningTests = 3,
}
```

I understand why the enum values don't match exactly ([info](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wwsapi/thread/2aee66b6-a387-44f3-88cb-71892b148822)). Everything works as expected except that when I pass WsStateHungOrBroken to web service, it cannot interpret it correctly and simply convert it to 0. It should really be 5 which is how it is defined in web service.

If anyone can explain to me why it is like this or how i can debug further, that would be useful. As a note, I've tried SvcTraceViewer but no luck in finding out what data is being passed in between service and my application.

**Edit**: Found solution at http://thorarin.net/blog/post/2010/08/08/Controlling-WSDL-minOccurs-with-WCF.aspx#comment
By default all WCF method parameters are IsRequired=False and when enum value is 0, WCF treats this as empty value and don't pass it to service at all and service use default value. Making all parameters required fixes the issue.

Comment: Why are you specifically assigning numbers to your enum?

Comment: They are mapped to IDs in my database

Answer (score 1):

The very [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wwsapi/thread/2aee66b6-a387-44f3-88cb-71892b148822) you supplied tells you why this happens. The numeric values of the `enum` are not preserved. Since `HungOrBroken` is first in alphabetical order, it will have the value 0 on the client side.

This is exactly what you posted in your question.

Comment: What I meant is that yes in auto-gen code it is 0 and that is fine. But when web service receives the value, regardless of what integer value c++ code had, it should be converted into HungOrBroken and not just 0 which doesn't map to anything.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. You should use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to see what's being sent on the wire. I bet it sends "0" for that one. See what it sends for the others - then complain to Microsoft!